# awk conditional statement based on a value between colon

Tags: awk

I was just introduced to awk and I'm trying to retrieve rows from my file based on the value on column 10.
I need to filter the data based on the value of the third value if ":" was used as a separator in column 10 (last column).

Here is an example data in column 10. `0/1:1,9:10:15:337,0,15`.

I was able to extract the third value using this command `awk '{print $10}' file.txt | awk -F  ":" '/1/ {print $3}'`
This returns the value 10 but how can I return other rows (not just the value in column 10) if this third value is less than or greater than a specific number?
I tried this `awk '{if($10 -F ":" "/1/ ($3<10))" print $0;}' file.txt` but it returns a syntax error.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please confirm in value `0/1:1,9:10:15:337,0,15` which value you want to get?

Comment: `-F ":"` is an option and should not be embedded in the middle of the script. The correct way to pass it is `awk -F ":" '... your script here ...'` but the script has some additional problems which are hard to sort out in a comment.

Comment: The `awk | awk` pipeline can be refactored to a single Awk script. The `split` function allows you to do a second split of one or more fields on a different delimiter into an array.
 `awk '$10 ~ /1/ {split($10, a, ":"); print a[3] }' file.txt` To add a check if the third field is less than 10, that would be `awk '$3<10 && $10 ~ /1/ { split($10, a, ":"); print a[3] }' file.txt`

Comment: I strongly recommend using bioinformatics software for bioinformatics tasks to reduce the risk of unforeseen errors. [bcftools](https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html) is better suited for filtering variants than awk. For further bioinformatics-related questions, the community at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ is very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
awk '{print $10}' file.txt | awk -F  ":" '/1/ {print $3}'
```

should be just 1 awk script:

```
awk '$10 ~ /1/ { split($10,f,/:/); print f[3] }' file.txt
```

but I'm not sure that code is doing what you think it does. If you want to print the 3rd value of all $10s that contain `:`s, as it sounds like from your text, that'd be:

```
awk 'split($10,f,/:/) > 1 { print f[3] }' file.txt
```

and to print the rows where that value is less than 7 would be:

```
awk '(split($10,f,/:/) > 1) && (f[3] < 7)' file.txt
```